# MVC2 --> MVC3 Upgrade

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, upgrade

As today's MVC3 released, I would like to ask if anyone had experienced problems in upgrading from MVC2 to MVC3 (without changing anything in the views) .

I'm currently using EF4, Telerik extensions

Should I upgrade, or should I wait ?

Comment: Here is a link to the release information: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lead developer on the project I'm currently on installed and upgraded MVC2 to MVC3 RC, and the project and we're using EF4 and Telerik.

We updated from RC to the release this morning and discussed the update from MVC2 to MVC3 RC.  After installation, he had to update the project references and web.config, but was able to do it fairly painlessly.

Make sure any other developers working on the project install the framework it to prevent any issues after taking an updated copy of the solution that you check in after upgrading.

Comment: 10x, it looks promising, maybe I should wait a week, for Telerik's followup on this release, but I understand that you passed it clearly (with a samll change to web.config...)

Comment: Oh, and never forget to update assemblyBinding in web.config
it will work for some pages, and will crash w3wp process for others )

Comment: We also ran into an issue where one of our web clients referenced a dll that used mvc2 dlls.  It would compile fine, but w3wp would crash at runtime.  We noticed the old mvc2 dlls by opening ResourceMon and seeing the dll in the mvc2 dll inexplicably loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I have been also thinking same. Expecially Telerik controls should work 100% because we're using them a lot.

There are some information in the Telerik forums regarding ASP.NET MVC 3:

[Telerik Extensions for MVC 3 RTM](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/telerik-extensions-for-mvc-3-rtm.aspx)

and some other threads regarding Razor engine + Telerik controls. Probably you're not converting all your views to Razor, so you don't encounter those problems.

Comment: 10x for the info, I'll look for that release.

Answer (score 0):

We made the move and even after updating the web.config are having issues with the Telerik controls not working.  This is taking a working MVC2 site using Telerik MVC2 controls and simply installing MVC3 on the server and updating the config.  There are no other changes to the codebase.

Strangely this affects the test server but not the dev server, even though the dev servers do not have Telerik MVC3 controls installed.  Still investigating...