# .NET: Advice for updating solution to .NET 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

We have a solution containing an ASP.NET MVC web app, a web forms website project, a windows service and a heap of class libraries.

We are being upgraded to use VS2010 and would like to use all the new goodness in .NET 4.

Are there any issues we need to consider here? Can anyone provide any advice?

Comment: Currently which framework u using.

Comment: Good question. VS2008, MVC 2, .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

i have upgraded my app containing mvc and webform using the tool [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008). i didn't find any serious problem while upgrading. You can read further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690958/mvc2-mvc3-upgrade)

Comment: If we have any difficulties, I'll check this out.

Answer (score 1):

IIS configuration files (web.config) are quite simplified using .NET 4, as a big part of the default is now not part of the file (it's now defined at machine level). Therefore, if you don't change your web.config file, there will be redondant config info in it resulting in an error at startup.

I would advice you to look at the web.config file of a new ASP.NET MVC project in VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

there are many features you can use like

- In web forms project

  1. If your pages have javascripts you can use [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) attribute of web controls.
  2. Creating your custom output cache provider for caching [check this](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/19/asp-net-4-0-writing-custom-output-cache-providers.aspx).
  3. you can set your meta tags by using `Page.MetaKeywords` and `Page.MetaDescription` properties.
  4. You can use friendly urls by using routing [check this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx)
- In all Application

  1. you can use [dynamic types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)
  2. use [automatic properties](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/12/04/c-3-0-features-automatic-properties.aspx) to save using `private variable`

Comment: Although this is useful information, it's not strictly speaking an answer to my question. Thanks all the same!